# Log an objective-c pointer and if it is weak or strong

Tags: objective-c

I am debugging and it would be really helpful if I can log a pointer along with if it is weak or strong, something like

```
NSLog( @"Pointer is %p and weak %@", p, [p isWeak] ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
```

Is this possible?

The pointer is to a block but that is not really relevant to the question although it is relevant to the bug I am trying to fix.

Comment: It's possible, but it requires quite a lot of work. Some resources where you can start - [_objc_isTaggedPointer](https://github.com/0xxd0/objc4/blob/c4f8494416ed4e95a1707afbf4c93bced0de65d0/objc4/runtime/objc-internal.h#L442-L446), [isWeaklyReferenced](https://github.com/0xxd0/objc4/blob/c4f8494416ed4e95a1707afbf4c93bced0de65d0/objc4/runtime/objc-object.h#L369-L375), ... All these things are Objective-C internals and not available to you - they can be (are) inlined, you have to copy & paste them from the Obj-C runtime source to use them, ...

Comment: I wouldn't expect that anyone will answer with a copy & pasted code that does this. The question here is - why do you even need this?

Comment: It seems the debugger is able to get a lot of info from just a pointer, even if to a block. If it was to an NSObject I would be able to e.g. print the class and description. I did not really expect it to be possible but, given that it is objective-c and ARC I was hoping somehow this might be doable and even copy & paste easy. The bug (that NSDictionary & block one) I wanted to investigate was to ensure that a pointer that obviously should be strong is in fact also seen as strong by the compiler. But I think in general it would be nice if you could check a pointer and log out its *strength*.

Comment: Is `pointer` the variable or the address? Is [retainCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571952-retaincount?language=occ) what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Willeke - you mean that one with the **do not use this method** warning!? Not really but it sounds exciting. The debugger seems to know a lot about pointers. When the compiler wraps a block pointer in ```__NSMallocBlock__``` the debugger reports it as such. I ran into some block problems and wanted to check whether a pointer to some block is strong. Another use case is all the weakly held pointers to UI elements in your app. Maybe in some situation you want to confirm that some pointer, say ```self.label``` is actually weak and a debug dump is much easier than decyphering reams of code.

Comment: A pointer being weak or strong is not inherent in the pointer itself -- it's a matter of local scope, usually.  If you retain a pointer to make it strong in a particular scope, it's still the same pointer.  You can find out if an object's property is marked weak -- those are in the property attributes.  But for local variables, if the debugger knows it, that's because it has some of the compiler smarts as well, so it knows how the compiler is treating a pointer in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I stumbled on this which I think will work, albeit only for Objective-C properties.

The `property_getAttributes` function returns a (C) string that can be checked for a number of 'flags' such as **W** which indicates it is a weak reference for example. It requires a bit of parsing but at least it seems easily doable.

So as far as copy and paste code goes, how about this ... reworking the manual example a bit to print out the 'weakness'.

```
id LenderClass = objc_getClass("Lender");

unsigned int outCount, i;

objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(LenderClass, &outCount);

for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {

    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    char * attr = property_getAttributes(property);

    fprintf(stdout, "%s %s (weak %s)\n", property_getName(property), attr, strstr( attr, ",W" ) ? "YES" : "NO" );

}
```